# How to set button background based on item property - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating Radio Buttons dynamically that means I'm looping throught my database items and I'm displaying styled radio buttons and here's my code:

```
public ObservableCollection<Product> products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(ProductsController.SelectAllProducts());

if (products.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(var item in products)
    {
        SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        mySolidColorBrush = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#004a80"));
        RadioButton a = new RadioButton();
        a.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
        a.Background = Brushes.Green;
        a.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        a.BorderBrush = mySolidColorBrush;
        a.Width = 118;
        a.Height = 70;
        a.Margin = new Thickness(5,0,0,5);
        Style style = Application.Current.Resources["MyRadioButtonAsButtonStyle"] as Style;
        a.Style = style;
        a.ApplyTemplate();
        a.Content = item.OrdinalNumber;
        Image imgControl = (Image)a.Template.FindName("img", a);
        Image imgControlWhite = (Image)a.Template.FindName("whiteImg", a);
        TextBlock text = (TextBlock)a.Template.FindName("text", a);

        if (fileNames.Count > 0)
        {
            if (!fileNames.Any(item.Description.Contains))
            {
                item.IsProcessed = true; // SETTING PROPERTY
            }
        }


        a.Click += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            var radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
            MessageBox.Show(radioButton.Content.ToString());
        };
        text.Text = item.Title;
        imgControl.Source = image;
        spProducts.Children.Add(a);
    }
}
```

I'm setting `IsProcessed` which I would like to use when I'm setting background of this radio button which is styled as button.

So for example if `IsProcessed = true` I would like to set `Background` to `Green`, otherwise I would like to set it to `Red`.

Here is my class:

`enter code here`public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Attributes
    private string _ordinalNumber;
    private string _title;
    private string _description;
    private bool _isProcessed;
    #endregion

```
#region Properties
public string OrdinalNumber
{
    get { return _ordinalNumber; }
    set { _ordinalNumber = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("OrdinalNumber"); }
}
public string Title
{
    get { return _title; }
    set { _title = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Title"); }
}
public string Description
{
    get { return _description; }
    set { _description = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Description"); }
}

public bool IsProcessed
{
    get { return _isProcessed; }
    set
    {
        _isProcessed = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsProcessed");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

And here is my custom style where I've set background for first time (To Green):

```
  <Style x:Key="MyRadioButtonAsButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
            <Setter Property="GroupName" Value="Option" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.5" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <!-- and so on for each property...-->
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <Border Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=parentStackPanel}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=parentStackPanel}" BorderBrush="#004a80" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <Grid x:Name="gridProduct" Background="Green">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="80*"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Image x:Name="slika" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" Visibility="Visible"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="tekst" Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,0,3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12"></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="gridProduct" Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="tekst" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

So basically I don't know how to check value of `item.IsProcessed` in `app.xaml` so I might somehow add setter for background depending on that prop value?

Any kind of help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: You could implement `IValueConverter`, which would convert bool to background object.

Comment: And you should consider using an ItemsControl instead of creating UI elements in code behind.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn How could I do that? Could you help me and provide an example, I'm struggling with this since yesterday :(

Comment: @Clemens Since my elements depending on how many items I have in database I thought creating it like this might be good, could you provide your example please? Thanks

Comment: There are really plenty of ItemsControl examples here on StackOverflow. The central idea is to bind the ItemsSource property to a collection of data item objects and define an ItemTemplate to visualize the items. Then perhaps also utilize the ItemContainerStyle and ItemsPanel properties.

Comment: For the "Background based on an item property", this would usually be done by a DataTrigger with a Binding to the item property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a `DataTrigger`to your `Style`?:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="gridProduct" Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
        <Setter TargetName="tekst" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </Trigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsProcessed}" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="gridProduct" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

For the binding to work, you should set the `DataContext` of the `RadioButton`:

```
foreach (var item in products)
{
    ...
    a.DataContext = item;
    spProducts.Children.Add(a);
}
```

In general, you would use an `ItemsControl` that binds to the `ObservableCollection<Product>` and define the `RadioButton` in the `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: who's the boss? mm8 is the boss ! Thanks sir a lot!